# How to get only Integer values from a column

Tags: sql, select, databricks

I'm using SQL in Databricks and I wish to create a view of a table. The data looks similar to this:

```
A   |    B    |    C
------------------------
AA  |    AB   |    1
AA  |    AC   |    1.5
AA  |    AD   |    2
AA  |    AE   |    3
```

And basically, what I want to do is read in the table such that only the rows when `C` has integer values are read in, so that I get:

```
A   |    B    |    C
------------------------
AA  |    AB   |    1
AA  |    AD   |    2
AA  |    AE   |    3
```

I've tried using code similar to this:

```
WHERE df.C NOT LIKE '.%[0-9$]%'
```

But this doesn't work, and similarly I tried this too:

```
Where IsNumeric(df.C) = 0x1
```

But `IsNumeric` doesn't seem to work in Databricks. If anyone has any ideas I'd greatly appreciate it, thank you!

Comment: What is the data type of column C?

Comment: It is a `double` data type

Comment: You could try to do it mathematically `where TRY_CAST(C AS INT) - C = 0`